# Change the file name by using python

Tags: python, image, jpeg, file-rename, batch-rename

I would like to change the file name in the folder, there are jpg file but corrupted with product id number. I tried to rename it and delete the string after ".jpg" by using python, here is the code, but there is no any change.

Do you guys have any suggestion?

```
import os

path=input('C:\\Users\\pengoul\\Downloads\\Files\\PIC\\')    

def rename(path):

    for file in os.listdir(path):

        if file.endswith(".jpg@v=*"):
            print(file)

            newfile=file.split("@",1)[0]
        
            newName=file.replace(file,newfile)
                    
            os.rename(os.path.join(path,file),os.path.join(path,newName))
 
rename(path)

print("End")
```

Rename the file of one folder and delete the string after .jpg by using python.

Comment: a hack is to create a new file with the same content, and delete the older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you input path from user, python automatically use "\" instead of "\\" so you shouldn't use "\\" while input. So I suggest one of these two ways:

```
path = input("Input your Path: ")
# And the user entered this: C:\Users\pengoul\Downloads\Files\PIC
```

or

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\pengoul\\Downloads\\Files\\PIC'
```

or

```
path = r'C:\Users\pengoul\Downloads\Files\PIC'
```

I hope that works for you. If not, make us aware of that!